# How to update multiple rows in mysql with php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I would like to update multiple rows in a mysql database with php with this code it updates only the last one. What do I need to add so it will update all the rows?

```
    <?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "cases";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

    $Famas_Doomkitty_mn          =       1,54;
    $Famas_Doomkitty_ft          =       1,46;
    $Famas_Doomkitty_mnst          =       2,57;
    $Famas_Doomkitty_ftst          =       2,42;


$sql = "UPDATE esports2013skins SET FAMASDoomkitty='$Famas_Doomkitty_mn' WHERE id=2";

$sql = "UPDATE esports2013skins SET FAMASDoomkitty='$Famas_Doomkitty_ft' WHERE id=3";

$sql = "UPDATE esports2013skins SET FAMASDoomkitty='$Famas_Doomkitty_mnst' WHERE id=7";

$sql = "UPDATE esports2013skins SET FAMASDoomkitty='$Famas_Doomkitty_ftst' WHERE id=8";



if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with an array and a foreach like this:

```
$sql_querys = [
            "UPDATE esports2013skins SET FAMASDoomkitty='$Famas_Doomkitty_mn' WHERE id=2",
            "UPDATE esports2013skins SET FAMASDoomkitty='$Famas_Doomkitty_ft' WHERE id=3",
            "UPDATE esports2013skins SET FAMASDoomkitty='$Famas_Doomkitty_mnst' WHERE id=7",
            "UPDATE esports2013skins SET FAMASDoomkitty='$Famas_Doomkitty_ftst' WHERE id=8"
        ];
        foreach($sql_querys as $sql){
            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "Record updated successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
            }
        }
```